# How do i display only Task of this week - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I Want to display only the task from this week, but so far I have only be able to group them.

views:

```
      <% @task_months.each do |month, tasks| %>
      <% for task in tasks %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= link_to task.name, task %></td>
          <%if task.due_date? %>
            <td>due on <%= task.due_date.strftime("%B %d, %Y")  %></td>
          <% end %>
          <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_task_path(task), class: "btn btn-info" %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', task, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: "btn btn-danger" %></td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
```

Controller:

```
def week_task
@tasks = Task.order(:due_date)
  @task_months = @tasks.group_by {|t| t.due_date.beginning_of_week }
end
```

Im using devise, and i also want to display the task of the `current_user` and the @tasks of the week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@task_months = @tasks.where('due_date >= ? AND due_date <= ?', Time.current.beginning_of_week, Time.current.end_of_week)
```

And for current user tasks, something like:

```
@task_months = @tasks.where('user_id = ?', current_user.id)
```

Or combining the two for tasks for the current user's tasks this week:

```
@task_months = @tasks.where('due_date >= ? AND due_date <= ? AND user_id = ?', Time.current.beginning_of_week, Time.current.end_of_week, current_user.id)
```

Comment: Thank you so much i have been struggling with this for a while